# Changing Wine dlls overrides configuration from terminal

Tags: wine, libraries

Well, I have a problem with two Wine programs. One of the need a DLL with a `"(native,builtin)"` configuration and the other with any configuration but that one.

So my question is that is there a way to overwrite or change from the terminal (to put it on a script) that configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can use `WINEDLLOVERRIDES` environment variable

  ```
  export WINEDLLOVERRIDES="shell32=n,b"
  wine ...
  ```

  or inline:

  ```
  WINEDLLOVERRIDES="shell32=n,b" wine ...
  ```
- May be its better to create a new profile that specific application.

  1. Open Wine Configure or `winecfg` from command-line.
  2. Go to *Applications* tab → Add application
  3. Select that profile then go to *Libraries* tab and add needed DLL overrides.

Reference:

- `man wine`